# Regular Expression debug

Tags: javascript, regex

I need some help with my regular expression, here is what I have so far:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9\S\W]{2,}\d$/
```

And this is what I want to do: only a username that has alphanumeric characters (lower and upper case letters and numbers allowed only - no spaces, no underscores), has at minimum 2 characters, and has a number as the final character (such as 'Fyard1') is accepted via my form.

Thank you for your help guys!

Comment: `/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\d$/`? Note that `\S` matches any non-whitespace char, and `\W` matches any whitespaces alongside all non-word chars, so your `[a-zA-Z0-9\S\W]` matches any chars, same as `[\w\W]`.

Comment: note, if you'd like to test your Regex Code try [Regexr](https://regexr.com/).

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much.

Comment: Please kindly upvote my answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
/^(?=.*\d$)[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,}$/
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/dpAF4T/1).

`^` finds the beginning of the string, `(?=.*\d$)` requires a digit at the end, `a-zA-Z0-9]{2,}` matches two or more digits or letters and `$` checks the end of string.

Comment: Thank you so much dear friend I really appreciate your help.